# Getting notifications for question I no longer care about

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications

I posted a question a few years ago for a bug in the IDE I was using at the time. Now, every time I come back to stackoverflow, I see notifications for people voting or commenting on this question. I could not care less about the question anymore and I've basically been conditioned to hate my notifications now, because they're just noise. I want to keep the question around to help others who had the issue, but really don't care to be notified about it. Is there anything I can do, other than request the question be locked, or delete it?

Comment: You can request disassociation.  Flag the question, use other.

Comment: Good idea. Did that

Comment: Are you very sure? It will be as if you never asked that question, which means you lose all reputation gained from the votes.

Comment: Ah man, didn't know that. Well given that most of my reputation is coming from just asking this question at the right time and place, I feel kinda weird that I've gotten as much of a boost from it as I have. So I guess yeah I'd be fine with sacrificing my rep for no more noise

Comment: @SamuelLiew ^^^ Since he didn't ping you, not sure you're seeing the reply in comments...

Comment: Thanks for the confimation.. I have submitted the disassociation request.